# Bold is getting ignored by my captions

Tags: luatex

**update:**
It might be that my font has no bold "ability".

**Test1** on Overleaf:
Does my font not have boldness, or what?

[image: no boldness wt]

**Test2:**

I commented out my own font `\setmainfont{myfont.ttf}` and the caption got bold

**Test3:**

I don't know which fonts have bold feature, but I tried

https://www.freefontspro.com/de/14454/arial.ttf

And `\textbf` doesn't work, either.

---

The caption of m figure is not getting **bold**.

bf is ignored

I'd like to have:

(German)
**Abbildung 1 :** test figure

The following code is for lua tex. I included a file `myfont.ttf`.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Dokumententyp 
% Überschriften typ
\documentclass[report]{scrreprt} 
%%%% Schrift
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec} %% 1. for ttf
%Zeilenabstand:
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%Setze Schriftart:
\setmainfont{myfont.ttf}
% Seitenverhältnisse:
%https://www.namsu.de/Extra/pakete/Geometry.html
 \usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry} 

% Sprache
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%%%%%%%%%%%% Header / Footer Lines
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
%\chead{}
%\rhead{\slshape \rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%\lfoot{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Abbildung
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption} %% just doesnt work...
   

%\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
\usepackage{placeins} %% float barrier...
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Literaturverzeichnis

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CODE  Listings?
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
%New colors defined below
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
%Code listing style named "mystyle"
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour}, commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,                 
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=10pt,                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=1,
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}






%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %% ???
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
% Absatzgröße
\setlength{\parskip}{1em plus 0.25em minus 0.25em}


% ?
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,setspace,pstricks,booktabs,mathtools,amsmath}

\begin{document}


\include{1_Einleitung}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you make sure that the font you're using has bold characters?

Comment: its not a stupid question. I didnt make sure. How can I do it best?

Comment: Depending on your operating system, you could just open it in the default font tool (on macOS it'd be Font Book, for example).

Comment: i have ubuntu I could try to open it with libre office.

Comment: Could you try with another TTF font that you know has bold characters (by testing it in another application)? Or tell us which font you're trying to use?

Comment: Unrelated, but mixing `fancyhdr` with a KOMA-Script class is probably a bad idea.

Comment: "Unrelated, but mixing fancyhdr with a KOMA-Script class is probably a bad idea" how to solve this ?

Comment: @pgapga This probably should be asked as a separate question (unless it's already been asked, I haven't made a search).

Comment: Use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead. Do not use `tocloft` etc. either. In general, don't ignore warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood, you might have two problems. The first one, as discussed in the comments, is that you need to make sure that your font has bold characters.

The second one is simply that you used the wrong option for captions:

`\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}` makes the *text* of the caption bold, while:

`\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}` makes the *label* of the caption bold.

If your font has bold character, this should work.

Unrelated problems about your code:

- The KOMA classes are quite unfriendly to external packages. You should avoid `fancyhdr` as Ingmar said, but during compilation you also get messages warning that using `tocbibind` is also not a good idea. In general, if you really want to use a KOMA class, read [its documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) carefully to know which proprietary commands the class has to replace some other packages.
- Do you really need to load both `minted` and `listings` in the same file? If you don't know, I'd recomment `listings`, which gives similar results without the unpleasant need to use shell escape.
- Do you really need `pstricks`? It's an old package relying on an obsolete format, so unless you're sure that you have code requiring it, it isn't a package that you should be relying on in 2022.

Comment: *The KOMA classes are quite unfriendly to external packages.* Usually it's the other way round, KOMA-Script is very well-documented and actually goes out of its way trying to play nice with other packages, but if you are using low-level code, sometimes things can break in interesting ways.

*In general, if you really want to use a KOMA class* … Just for the record: I strongly recommend it to European users, just go KOMA all the way and use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `fancyhdr` etc.